Power Shell script to automate need to install modules
Load required assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
function Show-MessageBox {
param (

    [string]$message,

    [string]$title

)

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, $title)

}
function Run-Queries {
param (

    [string]$selectedDate

)



$queries = @(

    "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_column = TO_DATE('$selectedDate', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"

) * 10



$connectionString = "User Id=username;Password=password;Data Source=hostname/service_name"



try {

    $connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)

    $connection.Open()



    $excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path 'your_excel_file.xlsx'

    $worksheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets[2] # Sheet number 3 (index 2)

    $worksheet.Cells.Clear()



    $progressBar.Maximum = $queries.Length

    $progressBar.Value = 0



    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $queries.Length; $i++) {

        $statusLabel.Text = "Status: Running query $($i + 1)"

        [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()



        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()

        $command.CommandText = $queries[$i]

        $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()



        $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

        $dataTable.Load($reader)



        $rowIndex = $worksheet.Dimension?.End.Row + 1

        if ($null -eq $rowIndex) { $rowIndex = 1 }



        Export-Excel -Worksheet $worksheet -Append -InputObject $dataTable -StartRow $rowIndex -StartColumn 1 -TableName "QueryData"



        $progressBar.Value = $i + 1

    }



    Close-ExcelPackage -ExcelPackage $excel



    $connection.Close()

    Show-MessageBox -message "All queries executed successfully." -title "Success"

} catch {

    Show-MessageBox -message "An error occurred: $_" -title "Failure"

}

}
Create the form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Oracle Query Executor"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 300)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
Create a date picker
$datePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker.Format = [System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat]::Short
$datePicker.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$form.Controls.Add($datePicker)
Create a progress bar
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 50)
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 30)
$form.Controls.Add($progressBar)
Create a status label
$statusLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$statusLabel.Text = "Status: Waiting to start"
$statusLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 90)
$form.Controls.Add($statusLabel)
Create a button
$runButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$runButton.Text = "Run Queries"
$runButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 130)
$runButton.Add_Click({
$selectedDate = $datePicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Run-Queries -selectedDate $selectedDate

})
$form.Controls.Add($runButton)
Show the form
$form.ShowDialog()
I want to install modules but I am not able to do it.

90% of your sample code is about creating a Windows Form - can you distill it down to demonstrate the exact issue you're having with installing a module? And please include any error messages, or expand on "I am not able to do it." with some more details. Also, the formatting on your sample code could do with a tidy up...

# Database connection parameters
$server = "your_database_server"
$database = "your_database_name"
$username = "your_username"
$password = "your_password"

# Construct the connection string
$connectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User Id=$username;Password=$password;"

# Define the query to execute
$query = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;"

# Create a connection object
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

# Open the connection
$connection.Open()

# Create a command object
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

# Execute the query and store the results
$results = $command.ExecuteReader()

# Loop through the results (in this case, we expect only one result)
while ($results.Read()) {
    # Print the result (assuming there is only one column in the result set)
    Write-Host "Current date from database: $($results.GetValue(0))"
}

# Close the connection and dispose of objects
$connection.Close()
$connection.Dispose()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Code-only answers are discouraged. Please say more about how this answers the question.
